# Which of the following groups is not cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Which of the following groups is not cyclic?
>
> (a) $G_1 = \{2, 4,6,8 \}$ w.r.t. $\odot$
>
> (b) $G_2 = \{0,1, 2,3 \}$ w.r.t. $\oplus$ (binary XOR)
>
> (c) $G_3 =$ Group of symmetries of a rectangle w.r.t. $\circ$ (composition)
>
> (d) $G_4 =$ $4$th roots of unity w.r.t. $\cdot$ (multiplication)

Can anyone explain me this question?

Comment: I've interpreted three of the four operations used; but the square has me stumped. What is the operation? Furthermore, please use a _descriptive_ title for your question. For obvious reasons, "Can anyone explain me this question?" does not qualify.

Comment: @Lord_Farin there is a circle and a dot inside that circle! sorry for absurd things!

Comment: So what is the operation $\odot?$  What is $2 \odot 6?$

Comment: @RossMillikan yes..this is the operation..but trust me, i dont kno what that means.

Comment: @joeyrohan: For $d$ see this link, [Roots of Unity under Multiplication form Cyclic Group](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Roots_of_Unity_under_Multiplication_form_Cyclic_Group).

Comment: @BabakS. Thanks Alot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  For a group to be cyclic, there must be an element $a$ so that all the elements can be expressed as $a^n$, each for a different $n$.  The terminology comes because this is the structure of $\Bbb {Z/Z_n}$, where $a=1$ works (and often others).  I can't see what the operator is in your first example-it is some sort of unicode.  For b, try each element $\oplus$ itself.  What do you get?  For c, there are two different types of symmetry-those that turn the rectangle upside down and those that do not.

Comment: Is there some easy concept for this? Its difficult for me to understand :(

Comment: My example of integers $\pmod n$  with modular addition seems the easiest.  For example, if $n=5$, you have all the elements of the group as $\{1,1+1,1+1+1,1+1+1+1,1+1+1+1+1\}$ so the group is cyclic.  For $\BbbS_3$, the six element group of symmetries of a triangle, there is no way to do this-you have the elements that flip the triangle over and the ones that do not.  You can't go through all six elements by repeating any one.

Comment: but $\oplus$ what does that mean???

Comment: $\oplus$ seems to be the bitwise XOR-but wherever you got the problem should tell you.  So $2 \oplus 3 =1$ if I am interpreting it correctly.  Maybe $\odot$ is the bitwise product?  Just guessing.

Comment: The question i had placed, its till that much...nothing else.MAY god bless me with maths..!!